# Chrome extensions - can I show the bookmark toolbar programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to show or hide the bookmark toolbar programmatically on some events.

Can it be done with an extension for Chrome, or is that in the user domain?

If it can be done where should I look it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do from an extension, only user may control this bar visibility.

Comment: I know they say to avoid mimicking the standard new tab page but are there resources for mimicking the bookmarks bar and adding that as an option in my extension?